# Nested OnClickListeners

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm writing a program that displays a list of buttons, each of which represents a different attraction in a certain city. Upon clicking the button, a dialog box is supposed to present the user with two options, "More Info", and "Map It". Clicking on the "More Info" button will direct the user to the attraction's website, and the "Map It" button will display a page with the Google Map of the attraction.

My issue is that whenever the button for the attraction is clicked, I need to generate a AlertDialogBox with two buttons, who both have their own OnClickListeners. The problem happens when I try to create the two buttons on the AlertDialogBox. I'm getting an error that the buttons can not be created.

In another program, I tried creating an AlertDialogBox and it worked fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is. My code is below

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setTitle(name)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setMessage("Get More Information")
        .setNegativeButton(1, new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            )
            intent = new Intent(); 
           }
             })
             .create()
             .show(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you include the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

The method `setNegativeButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` takes a text ***Resource*** id, as parameter. For example: `R.string.my_string`, or `R.string.app_name` or whatever. The resource is not found, therefore your AlertDialog couldn't be created.

You might wanna change your 
`setNegativeButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` call

You can as well use `setNegativeButton(CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` Which takes a CharSequence(String is a CharSequence, you can pass one) as parameter (text) to display on the button like: `"More Info"` or `"Map It"`.

Also, instead of `getApplicationContext()` you might use `v.getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
            .setTitle(name)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setMessage("Get More Information")

            .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do operations
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly implementing your `.setNegativeButton()` method, ideally it should have 2 parameters,

1. Button text : this can either be a `String`(i.e. "Hello") or a `String
   resource` (i.e. R.string.hello) defined in the `strings.xml` file in
   `res/values` folder.
2. Second, has to be a `DialogInterface.onClickListener()` for listening
   to clicks on Dialog buttons, In its onClick you can perform you
   task.

   An ideal `AlertDialog` code may look like :

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder()                 
   builder.setTitle("Hello World")
   builder.setMessage("India is incredible.")
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       // Do something on Positive button click
       .
       .
       }
       })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       // Do something on Negative button click
       .
       .
       }
     })
   .setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             // Do Something on Back key press
             .
             .
          }
       return false;
      }
   }).create().show();
   ```

For more details about `AlertDialog.Builder` methods see the reference docs here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html